# Cálculo de dias vem negativo. Por que?

Tags: c#

Fiz isso:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
int dias = (int)dt.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays;
```

Se fizer para o dia de hoje(26/01/2018) o resultado na `var dias` é:

***-25***

Só queria saber porque veio negativo, só entender mesmo.

Comment: Quanto é 1 - 26?

Comment: Sim, achei que ele pegasse a data atual e subtraísse do dia 1. Mas é ao contrário.

Comment: `int dias = (int)DateTime.Today.Subtract(dt).TotalDays;` essa seria a conta

Answer (score 3):

Porque você está invertendo a ordem da sua comparação (para obter o resultado que espera):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
int dias = DateTime.Today.Subtract(dt).TotalDays;
```

**Explicando:**

O que você está fazendo é retornar a diferença em dias da data atribuída à variável `dt` e como na sua declaração de `int dias` você usa a data base ao substrair a data atual você está obtendo o valor negativo por "sobrar" dias.

Ex:

> 01/01/2018 - 26/01/2018 [em dias] = -25 dias (porque é uma data futura)